# Get Notified of Low Memory Crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, low-memory

I am trying to find a way to capture low memory crashes.
Most crash reporting tools, for example Crashlytics, do not capture low memory os kills.

https://twitter.com/crashlytics/status/235018252647010304
http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/123408-do-you-catch-out-of-memory-crashes

Does anyone know of any crash reporting tools that catch low memory crashes?
Or, does anyone know of a way to detect these crashes w/out any added reporting tools?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible.  If your app could "catch" a low memory termination, it could continue executing, which would defeat the purpose of the low memory termination.

Comment: Possible.  An app could periodically send memory stats as heartbeats to a monitor (another app or a server) or just record them locally.  Low memory warnings and stack dumps could also be recorded.  A break in the heartbeat may be interpreted as a crash.  The memory stats/warnings and lack of other crash information would serve as evidence.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "catch" a low memory warning, but you can be notified in advance of them happening. You can implement `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` in your app delegate or respond to the `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`. Aside from that, your app isn't notified when it's terminated.

You can also store transient data in `NSCache`, and it'll disappear under memory pressure.